# How can I interchange the sum signs

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-series

I need to interchange the sum signs in the following double summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}}\hat{g}(k)e^{2\pi ink\theta}n^{-s},$$
where $\mathbb{Z}^{\star}$ is the set of integers numbers excluded 0, $\hat{g}(k)$ is the Fourier coefficient of an analytic, 1 periodic function, real function, (so $|\hat{g}(k)|\leq Ck^{-\delta}$, for every $\delta>0$), $\theta$ is an irrational number and $s$ a complex number with $\sigma=\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$. The problem is, I can't prove that the double series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}}|\hat{g}(k)e^{2\pi ink\theta}n^{-s}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}}|\hat{g}(k)|n^{-\sigma}$$
converge. It seems, that since $|\hat{g}(k)|\leq Ck^{-\delta}$, for every $\delta>0$, I need to find a sequence $A(n)$ such that $|\hat{g}(k)|<k^{-A(n)}$, this is justified by the condition on $\hat{g}$, and $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^*}k^{-A(n)}<Cn^{-1},$$
where $C$ is a positive constant. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}}|\hat{g}(k)|n^{-\sigma}<C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1-\sigma}<\infty,$$
by the integral criterion. Does a sequence like $A(n)$ exist? Provided that sequence, is my argument correct? How can I find a sequence like this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from symbols, and supposing that I understood properly what you mean to achieve, let me present this just as a hint (too long for a comment).

If the $g(k)$'s are the Fourier coefficients, then they are tied to the amplitude (let's call them $A(k)$) of the harmonics composing the signal. The relating coefficient depends on how the Fourier series is defined.

Since you say that the originating signal is a real periodical function, then its power is limited (and maybe you can calculate it).
If it is so, then you know that the **sum of the squares** of the $A(k)$ is limited, and that should help you in carrying on the demonstration.

That is, if
$$
f(x) = f(x + 1) = {{A_{\,0} } \over 2} + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {A_{\,k} \cos \left( {2k\pi \,x + \varphi _{\,k} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{ - \;\infty \, < \,k\, < \,\infty \;} {c_{\,k} \;e^{\,i2k\pi \,x} } 
$$
with
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {{A_{\,0} } \over 2} = c_{\,0}  \hfill \cr 
  \left| {c_{\,k} } \right|\; = \left| {c_{\, - \,k} } \right| = {{A_{\,k} } \over 2} \hfill \cr 
  \varphi _{\,k}  = \arg \left( {c_{\,k} } \right)\quad \left| {\;1 \le k} \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

then
$$
\int_{x = 0}^{\,1} {f(x)^{\,2} dx}  = {{A_{\,0} ^{\,2} } \over 4} + {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {A_{\,k} ^{\,2} } 
$$

Which is the Power Theorem or [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem)

Comment: What do you mean by harmonics composing the signal ? What's the signal. Do you mean the function g? The Fourier series is defined by the series $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{g}(k)e^{2\pi ik }.$$ In my post I have represented the value $g(n\theta)$ by the converging, since g is real analytic, Fourier series. What do you mean by "power"? I cannot calculate anything since g is arbitrary, real analytic, periodic. Do you mean estimate? How do you define the $A(k)$ ?

Comment: @Mathitis: added some explanation

Comment: I still don't get it. Is the interchange of sum signs justified with your approach?

Comment: @Mathitis: you are right, since the moduli of the coefficients eventually decrease and become $<1$, then the fact that the sum of their squares is limited does not imply that their plain sum be limited. Sorry, I proposed a hint of no help.